# Novel closed-forms of integrals involving the Gudermannian function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, examples-counterexamples, special-functions

This week I'm trying to get integrals involving the Gudermannian function and other functions. My attempts are with Wolfram Alpha. I don't know if these integrals are in the literature are similar than $\int\operatorname{gd}(\log(\sin(x)))dx$ or $\int\operatorname{gd}(W(x))dx$, where $W(x)$ denotes the principal branch of Lambert W function. Wolfram Alpha online calculator knows how to compute the corresponding indefinite integrals.

I add below the reference [1] from Wikipedia for the Gudermannian function, that I've  denoted in this post as $\operatorname{gd}(x)$.

> **Question.** Explain how to get the indefinite integral for **a novel integral** (your example isn't in the literature: is your invention) **involving the Gudermannian function**, and get a definite integral from this (isn't required that this closed-form for the definite integral has mathematical beauty). **Many thanks.**

By application of trigonometric formulas, one can to consider more elaborated formulas as (if there aren't mistakes in my reasoning for real numbers $x>1$)$$\int\left(2\arctan\left(\frac{e^{W(x)}+W(x)}{1-x}\right)-\pi\right)\operatorname{mod }\pi\, dx.$$

Other available idea in this post is to use convergence theorems for series and limits to get more eleborated integrals than the previous.

Other interesting special function is the density and cumulative distribution of Gumbel distribution (see Wikipedia). Maybe one can to deduce other novel integrals involving the Gudermannian function, and pathological functions, or functions from mathematical physics (for example Hermite polynomials, see the online encyclopedias).

I think that the problem is interesting (the Gudermannian function and the Lambert W function are very interesting) as illustration of how to explore the creation of new integrals and the calculation of  some definite integral as application/consequence.

### References:

[1] The article [*Gudermannian function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) from Wikipedia.

Comment: I don't know if the examples that I've mentioned in the introductory paragraph are in the literature, in this case, please add the reference if you want to comment this fact, and I search and read how were computed my examples.

Comment: $\text{gd}(\ln(\sin(x)))=2\tan^{-1}(\sin(x))-\frac\pi2$ and $\text{gd}(\text W(x))=2\cot^{-1}\left(\frac {\text W(x)}x\right)-\frac\pi2$

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and comment @TymaGaidash ; I've tried to improve the chances to get a nice post adding more ideas, but I understand your comment in the way that the integrals of my first paragraph aren't novel integrals.

Comment: Since there are integrals in the expression, other attempt was to elaborate some integral involving the Gudermannian function and inspiration from the statement of problem *Problema 425.* by Seán M. Stewart from La Gaceta de la RSME, Vol. 24 (2021) (don't post please solutions for this problem of La Gaceta de la RSME since the solution will be published in the incoming number of La Gaceta de la RSME; I add this reference in the context of my post: get novel integrals involving the Gudermannian function).

Comment: Do you want closed forms of indefinite integrals of a function and gd$(x)$ or indefinite integrals that have a closed form in terms of gd$(x)$, shown by your $\int (\cdots)\mod\pi dx$ example?

Comment: First I want indefinite integrals that can be calculated, for example as the output of `int gd(lambertw(x))dx` from Wolfram Alpha online calculator (`gd` is the code for the Gudermannian function) and secondly that a definite integral can be computed from this (neither is required that the calculation is in  terms of particular values of elementary functions nor that such ' closed-form'  is nice in terms of mathematical beauty. Additionally if the users can to explain how were their creative process (why his/her integral works) it is better. Can be multiple integrals. Many thanks @TymaGaidash